# More CLOSE_WAIT on using keycloak-spring-security-adapter

Tags: spring-boot, tcp, httpclient, keycloak

On running load test on my spring-boot application, i could see more ports piled up in CLOSE_WAIT condition. Further drill down got me to the point that the CLOSE_WAIT is on the ports bound to keycloak.

I am using

> keycloak-spring-security-adapter Ver 3.4.3.Final

Is there a way to set the keepalive timeout in the keycloak adapter as we do with the HttpClient.

I tried running both keycloak and my application from my local host and captured the netstat output and furnishing here

> docker exec spanugo_api netstat -tan | grep CLOSE_WAIT 
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50276        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:33204        34.235.253.108:11006    CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50228        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50232        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50286        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:33182        34.235.253.108:11006    CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50224        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50234        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:33192        34.235.253.108:11006    CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50282        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:33186        34.235.253.108:11006    CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50236        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:33190        34.235.253.108:11006    CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50218        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50220        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50230        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:33194        34.235.253.108:11006    CLOSE_WAIT
>   tcp       32      0 172.20.0.6:50278        54.81.249.191:11006     CLOSE_WAIT

Also the wireshark output is below for one port on CLOSE_WAIT

[image]

I have extended "**KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**"

I could understand that adding ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy would fix the problem but unable to get the handle on adding the same as no where i could get the httpclient object.

Comment: In addition from wireshark, i could not see FIN being sent to the keycloak server from adapter

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple solution that limits connections to one.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${keycloak.json.path:classpath:keycloak.json}")
    private Resource keycloakJSON;

    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        //...
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakConfigResolver() {

            private KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;

            @Override
            public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request facade) {
                try {
                    // here is an important part!!!!
                    if (keycloakDeployment == null) {
                        keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(keycloakJSON.getInputStream());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return keycloakDeployment;
            }
        };
    }

}
```